# How to check if typed word is equal to any string from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string

I am trying to make input field (`onChange` method with props). When I input specific question (`string`), I get the answer for it. I managed to do it for single strings but I want to pass an array of strings instead of one string multiple times.

```
const newContent = (props) => {

let questions = '';
   if (props.question === "let") {
questions = <p> answer here </p>
   } else if (props.question === "var") {
questions = <p> answer here </p>
   } else if (props.question === "const") {
questions = <p> answer here </p>
   }

let nextQuestion = ["let", "var", "const"];
   if (props.question === nextQuestion) {
nextQuestion = <p> answer here </p>
   }
}
```

Comment: Is [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const anwers = 
    { let:   '<p> answer here for let </p>'
    , var:   '<p> answer here for var </p>'
    , const: '<p> answer here for const </p>'
    }

const newContent = props => anwers[props] ?  anwers[props] : 'bad value';

console.log( newContent('var'))
```

Comment: thanks for anwer  i dig object version but having problem to connect it to my input field. i managed to make it work with     {newContent(props.question)}  thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Something like ["let", "var", "const"].includes(props.question)